# Redirection operator in BAT file gives "Cannot open output file >"

Tags: windows, batch-file, io-redirection

I have a BAT script, with the last line being the problem

```
SET program=%1
SET PWD=%cd%

cd "%~dp0"

"%PWD%\%program%" "filename.txt" ^> "%PWD%\Output.txt" 2^>^&1
```

And this rightly spits out:

> "C:\path\program.exe" "filename.txt" > "C:\Path\Output.txt" 2>&1

However, it then says

> Cannot open output file >

And continues on with the script, without any file being created. If I copy and paste what is spit out, it run perfectly.

Note: The behavior is reproducible in an elevated CMD as well.

So, how do I get an EXE to run in a batch script, and redict both `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file, without getting an access error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your program.exe takes an parameter that is a filename.txt and outputs all to Output.txt

Try without the ^ simbols:

`"C:\path\program.exe filename.txt" > "C:\Path\Output.txt" 2>&1`

And batch cannot ask for permissions. If you are under c:\ you will need to execute the bat file with administration permission.

Comment: where did you see that ^> is used for redirection?

Comment: @David it's not, this is the normal case. Not sure what "everything you found" is, but it doesn't apply here.